# 'Microsoft.Web' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' in CSOM sharepoint

Tags: csom

I am new to CSOM and below is my first console application. the web is not recognising. Though all the dll in 15 hive are verified. Please help

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; 

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class DisplayWebTitle
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://****");            
            Site oSite = clientContext.Site;             
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web; 
            clientContext.Load(oWebsite);          
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy & Paste the entire contents of your C# file, I reckon there's a namespace you don't need that's confusing it.

Comment: using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
 { 
class DisplayWebTitle { static void Main() { ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://****");
Site oSite = clientContext.Site;
Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web; clientContext.Load(oWebsite);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    }
}
}

Comment: If the error is Microsoft.Web, then i think it's not resolving web properly. Try explicitly declaring web as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web

Comment: I dont see anything like using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.web

Comment: Not as a namespace, use Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = clientContext.Web

Comment: Oh yes thats solves the problem... but do i need to use the full extension everytime?

Comment: It's causing a conflict with class names being the same in two different assemblies. See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018419/class-with-same-name-in-two-assemblies-intentionally

Comment: Or, since you use client code, remove this using: `using Microsoft.SharePoint` statement that is for server side code

Comment: Right @RobertLindgren, nice find. Didn't see that there! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use client side code you should not add the `Microsoft.SharePoint` (since that one is for the server object model) to the usage statements, so your file should look like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; 

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class DisplayWebTitle
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://****");            
            Site oSite = clientContext.Site;             
            Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web; 
            clientContext.Load(oWebsite);          
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
    }
}
```